# How to get subtotal for an index from a pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to change the value format of a sub-column(Bill2) in a dataframe

The below output is obtained after i use pivot table function

```
data_frame4 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame4, 
                             index=['PC','Geo'], 
                             values=['Bill1', 'Bill2'], 
                             columns=['Month'], 
                             fill_value=0)
```

data_frame4 = data_frame4.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
    
tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame4.columns]
    
data_frame4.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

**My output:**

```
           jan               Feb
        Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo
A  Ind    1     1.28        1    1.28
B  US     1     1.28        1    1.28
C  Can    1     1.28        1    1.28
```

**My desired Output:**

```
           jan                Feb
       Bill1 Bill2        Bill1 Bill2

PC Geo
A  Ind   1    1.28           1    1.28
   Total 1    1.28           1    1.28
B  US    1    1.28           1    1.28
   Total 1    1.28           1    1.28 
C  Can   1    1.28           1    1.28
   Total 1    1.28           1    1.28
```

Comment: @jezrael.. bro how to calculate subtotal for **PC**... please ignore the currency symbols... i will convert the values to currency format at the end...first i need the subtotal for **PC**...also please be informed that there are 2 more indexes next to **PC**

Comment: @jezrael... bro can u help me out?

Comment: Can you add exocted outout from subtotal?

Comment: @jezrael... i have changed my **desired Output**.. please have a look at it

Comment: @jezrael.. can u see my **desired output**

Comment: I create solution, please create new question for subtotals and I add answer.

Comment: hmmm, so you get solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select only `Bill2` columns with [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) and then change values by [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with `format` or convert values to strings and prepend `$`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Bill2']] = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Bill2']].applymap('${:,.2f}'.format)
#alternative
#df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Bill2']] = '$' + df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Bill2']].astype(str)
#alternative1
#df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'Bill2')] = '$' + df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'Bill2')].astype(str)
print (df)
    jan          Feb       
  Bill1  Bill2 Bill1  Bill2
A     1  $1.28     1  $1.28
B     1  $1.28     1  $1.28
C     1  $1.28     1  $1.28
```